# plot a log natural and get gamma of image

Tags: matlab

link [b.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWzIH.jpg)

```
i=imread('b.jpg');
i1=rgb2gray(i);
i2=im2double(i);
j=log(1+i2);
```

1.

now this for get histograme of image.

```
 imhist(j);
```

say error:

```
??? Error using ==> iptcheckinput
Function IMHIST expected its first input, I or X, to be two-dimensional.

Error in ==> imhist>parse_inputs at 270
iptcheckinput(a, {'double','uint8','logical','uint16','int16','single'}, ...

Error in ==> imhist at 57
[a, n, isScaled, top, map] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});
```

=============================================================================

2.how can draw diagrame of function?

```
     plot(j,i2);

??? Error using ==> plot
Data may not have more than 2 dimensions
```

==============================================================================
3.how can get gamma of `j`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you have made a mistake in the beginning

```
i=imread('b.jpg');
i1=rgb2gray(i);
i2=im2double(i); % POSSIBLE MISTAKE
i2=im2double(i1);
j=log(1+i2);
```

After this correction, both (1) `imhist(j)` and (2) `plot(j,i2);` work OK. For gamma correction you can refer to either of these : [Link-A](http://www.mathworks.in/help/toolbox/images/ref/imadjust.html), [Link-B](http://www.graphics.cornell.edu/~westin/gamma/gamma.html).

Comment: im_gamma = (im/255).^0.45*255; return a matrix but i want only a number.